# Bug permits me to flag an answer as "not an answer" multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, not-an-answer

I was previously using this bug to my advantage, but now I'm being honest and reporting it. Anyway, normally, when you flag an answer as "not an answer" using the standard option and you have already flagged it as such (and the previous flag has been dismissed with a status),

[image]

you receive an error message:

[image]

However, you can flag it as not an answer again using the manual entry box:

[image]

...and the system will treat it as a normal not an answer flag, even though I have already flagged it previously as such. The proof:

[image]

This seemingly incorrect behavior should be replaced with one of the following:

- Treat it as a custom flag, which it appears to be.
- Reject the flag and complain that it has already been flagged as not an answer.

Anyway, it's a bug, and it could be used to one's advantage (keep flagging until it is deleted), and it should be fixed.

Comment: The only thing this accomplishes is your account being prevented from having this ability or worst the closure of your account

Comment: [status-completed] ... Details please?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Typing "not an answer" into the custom flag field on a post where one has already cast a standard NAA flag will give an error message instead of allowing one to submit a second NAA flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug. the previous flags are dismissed and you're flagging it for some other reason, perhaps the post has been vandalized again. It's up to you to *not* flag it multiple times.

And oh, don't be fooled thinking Mods don't notice this or others haven't tried this before. Frivolous flags are treated with disdain, and not only we decide to not take your flags seriously, the system will learn the same. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes, but see this [Meta.SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202336/how-was-my-custom-flag-disputed). They are normal NAA flags.

Comment: It's a bug for two reasons: 1) these flags get converted to a different type, which changes how they're processed... and 2) that change in type circumvents the normal checks that prevent the *exact* same flag from being raised multiple times.